# Why do I get "SyntexError: non-keyword arg after keyworkd arg" when my function doesn't specify keyword arguments?

Tags: python, function, syntax-error, keyword-argument, positional-argument

I read about positional arguments and keyword arguments, but I still don't understand why I get **SyntexError: non-keyword arg after keyworkd arg** from running the following code. I didn't specify any keyword arguments in my objective function, right?

```
def obj_func(center, P, ACCUM, sentiment):
    d = 0
    for row in range(ACCUM[sentiment-1],ACCUM[sentiment]):
        v = P[row,:]
        d += v.dot(center) / (norm(v) * norm(center))
    return(-d)

iter_init = np.array([random() for ele in range(k)])
CENTERS = dict()
for sentiment in range(3):
    CENTERS[sentiment] = minimize(obj_func, x0=iter_init, args(P,ACCUM,sentiment),)
```

Also, I'm not so sure the last comma in `minimize()`. The guy in the tutorial wrote like this. Is it correct?

Comment: No the last comma isn’t correct

Answer (score 1):

The error message is caused because in line `CENTERS[sentiment] = minimize(obj_func, x0=iter_init, args(P,ACCUM,sentiment),)` you have keyword agrument `x0=iter_init` and after that you have non-keyword argument `args(P,ACCUM,sentiment)`

Here `args` is a function you are calling and adding values it returns as an argument. I bet you want to give keyword argument named args which is a tuple. In that case you are missing `=` and right syntax would be `CENTERS[sentiment] = minimize(obj_func, x0=iter_init, args=(P,ACCUM,sentiment))`

If you are unsure, you can check arguments by saying `help(minimize)` in Python console once you've imported library providing that function.